# Octave output buffer completely messed up on OS X. How to fix?

Tags: macos, emacs, octave

I have just installed Octave 3.6 version on my MacBook. It uses emacs as its default editor, but it seems some regular emacs keys (such as C-x C-c for exiting) doesn't work in Octave emacs. Also, the output buffer gets completely messed when I try to use octave. Also, it always prints the prompt even when I'm in emacs. (See picture below)[image]

It seems it's parsing my input in the editor on the fly. But I have no idea how this could every happen.

Can anyone tell me what the problem is and how to fix it?

Comment: Wrong site for this question.

Comment: is that when you call the function `edit ()`? If so, you need to set the mode to sync.

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that you end up running the Emacs that comes bundled with Mac OS X (an old version of Emacs that only works in text mode) and you want to change that by installing a more recent version that can run in the GUI.  But that's just a wild guess.

Comment: How to make octave call editor in a separate window instead of inside the same one?

Comment: By doing as I suggest: install a more recent Emacs that can work in GUI mode (it will use GUI mode by default).

Comment: @OneZero by making octave open a separate terminal window and call emacs there. see my reply to your [other question](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18192498).